Getting a SSLContext using a self signed keystore on Android
i want to make my android application a server. i have a SocketServerManger class implementing WebSocketServer from  "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.5.6" liberary.
Java-WebSocket
as i connect to my server with ws connection it works correctly . the problem is when my client wants to connect to it with wss connection .
here is my code :
class SocketServerManger(
port: Int,
val socketListener: List<WebSocketConnectionListener>,
context: Context):WebSocketServer(InetSocketAddress(port)) {

var connection: WebSocket? = null

private val _isConnectionOpen = MutableStateFlow(false)
val isConnectionOpen: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isConnectionOpen

/*this part is added to set ssl context . without this part server works correctly with ws connection*/

init {
    createSSLContext(context)?.let {
        setWebSocketFactory(DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(it))
    }

}

private fun createSSLContext(context: Context): SSLContext? {
    try {
        val keystoreFileName = "keystore.bks"
        val keystorePassword = "password"
        val keystoreInputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(keystoreFileName)

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS")
        keyStore.load(keystoreInputStream, keystorePassword.toCharArray())
        keystoreInputStream.close()

       
       val keyManagerFactory =
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray())


       
        val tmf : TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("BKS");
        tmf.init(keyStore)

        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.trustManagers, SecureRandom())
        return sslContext
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        serverLog("createSSLContext ${e.message}")
    }
    return null
}

/*end of setup ssl*/

override fun onStart() {

    serverLog("SocketServerManger onStart")
    println("WebSocket server started")
}

override fun onOpen(conn: WebSocket?, handshake: ClientHandshake?) {
    connection = conn
    socketListener.forEach { it.onConnected() }
}

override fun onClose(conn: WebSocket?, code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {
   
    socketListener.forEach { it.onDisconnected(code, reason) }
}

override fun onMessage(conn: WebSocket?, message: String?) {
   
    socketListener.forEach { it.onMessage(conn, message) }

}

override fun onError(conn: WebSocket?, ex: Exception?) {
    socketListener.forEach { it.onError(ex) }
    ex?.printStackTrace()
}


suspend fun sendMessagesUntilSuccess(timeoutMillis: Long = 50000, message: String): Boolean {
    var success = false
    while (!success) {
        
        success = sendMessageWithTimeout(timeoutMillis, message)
        if (!success) {
           
            // Add a delay before retrying to avoid continuous retries and potential rate limiting
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
    return success
}

suspend fun sendMessageWithTimeout(timeoutMillis: Long = 5000, message: String): Boolean {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {
            withTimeout(timeoutMillis) {
                val result = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
                    try {
                        if (connection != null && connection!!.isOpen) {
                            connection!!.send(message)
                            true
                        } else {
                           
                            false
                        }
                    } catch (e: org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebsocketNotConnectedException) {
                        socketListener.forEach { it.onException(e) }
                        false
                    }
                }.await()

                result
            }
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            socketListener.forEach { it.onException(e) }
            false
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            socketListener.forEach { it.onException(e) }
            false
        }
    }
}


fun isConnectionOpen() = connection?.isOpen ?: false

fun isPortAvailable(port: Int): Boolean {
    return try {
        ServerSocket(port).close()
        true
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        false
    }
}

}
when i want to connect to the server with web client the connection time outs .

setting up ssl on android with self signed certificate requirs some steps which should be followed correctly otherwise you encounter some issues.
1/ Install OpenSSL
2/Generate a Private Key
Use OpenSSL to generate a private key
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048 
3/ Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
Use the private key to create a CSR
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem 
4/ Generate a Self-Signed Certificate
You can generate a self-signed certificate using the private key and CSR.
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
5/ Convert the Certificate to the Appropriate Format
android supports bks . first you should convert the certificate to PKCS#12 format with the extension .p12 or .pfx then to bks .
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -name "alias"
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore  certificate.bks -deststoretype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "D:\bcprov-debug-jdk18on-1.78.1.jar
6/ put the bks file format in your android project . i put it in my assets .
7/ set up ssl in your code :
` init {
createSSLContext(context)?.let {
    
    setWebSocketFactory(DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(it))
}

}
private fun createSSLContext(context: Context): SSLContext? {
val keystoreFileName = "certificate.bks"
val keystorePassword = "yourpassword"
val keystoreInputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(keystoreFileName)

try {

    val keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS")

    keystore.load(keystoreInputStream, keystorePassword.toCharArray())

    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, keystorePassword.toCharArray())
    val tmf : TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    tmf.init(keystore)

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers,tmf.trustManagers, null)
    return sslContext
} catch (e: Exception) {
  
    keystoreInputStream.close()
}
return null

}`
following these steps eventually resulted in connecting with wss.
